# postMessage from iFrame no longer works in CRM 2016 on premise

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, postmessage, dynamics-crm-2016

I've been using postMessage to communicate from an iFrame to CRM for some time now.  It worked in CRM 2011 and in CRM 2015 but it no longer works in CRM 2016.

iFrame javascript code:

```
    var pass_data = {
        'refresh': 'false',
        'expand': 'true'
    };        
    window.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(pass_data), 'crm url');
```

CRM javascript:

```
function setListener() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    //for browsers other than ie
    window.addEventListener("message", receivePostMessage, false);

  } else {
    //ie
    window.attachEvent('onmessage',receivePostMessage);

  }
} 

function receivePostMessage(event) {
   //do something with event.data
   var pass_data = JSON.parse(event.data);
   alert(pass_data);
  }
```

setListener() gets called on page load and I've confirmed that it is being called.  I've tried using a "*" as the target origin and it still doesnt work.

Does anyone know if this is still a viable option in CRM 2016?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CRM objectmodel changed with the introduction of turbo forms(CRM 2016), access the parent object of the form, which would be 2 levels up the iframe.

```
function setListener() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    //for browsers other than ie
    window.parent.addEventListener("message", receivePostMessage, false);
  } else {
    //ie
    window.parent.attachEvent('onmessage',receivePostMessage);
  }

window.parent.parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(pass_data), 'crm url');
```

Comment: I tried that it it's still not working.  I tried using the *, the CRM Url and the UrlReferrer.

Comment: Edited my answer, you need to use window.parent even when attaching the events, I thought it was self explanatory, my bad.

Comment: Another question:  How would I expand the iFrame height in javascript?  I used to use this:  document.getElementById("IFRAME_framename").style.height="400px";  but that isn't working anymore.  Does it have to be something like parent.document.getElementById("IFRAME_ConvertLead").style.height="400px";

Comment: If it is a fixed height, why don't you try to use the out of the box "Number of Rows" property and keep increasing the number till CRM renders it with the height you want? Goto form customizations --> iframe properties --> formatting --> Row Layout -->  Number of Rows